# C: why isn't my sort function changing the order of the numbers?

Tags: c, function

The sort function should change the order of the numbers scanned in from highest to lowest value. For example, if x = 6, y = 9, and z = 3, then the sort method should replace each variable: x = 9, y = 6, z = 3

```
//Sort function reorders parameters from highest to lowest value
int sort(int first, int second, int third) {
    
    if (first > second && first > third) {
        first = first;
        if ((first > second && first < third) || (first < second && first > third)) {
        first = second;
          if (first < second && first < third) {
             first = third;
          }
        }
    }

    if (second > first && second > third) {
        second = first;
        if ((second > first && second < third) || (second < first && second > third)) {
           second = second;
          if (second < first && second < third) {
            second = third;
          }
        }
    }
  
    if (third > first && third > second) {
        third = first;
        if ((third > first && third < second) || (third < first && third > second)) {
          third = second;
          if (third < first && third < second) {
            third = third;
           }
       }
    }
    return first;
    return second;
    return third;
}

int main() {
    int x, y, z;
    load(&x,&y,&z);
    print(x,y,z);
    printf("\nThe middle element is %2d", middleElement(x,y,z));
    sort(x,y,z);
    print(x,y,z);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those three values are passed in as *copies* of the original values (pass-by-value) which means any changes to them *within* the function will not affect the originals.

Also, it *looks* like you may believe the sequence:

```c
return first;
return second;
return third;
```

will somehow magically return all three values to the caller but that's not the case. It will return the first only (`return` is a transfer-of-control operation) and, since you don't assign that to anything in the caller, that will get thrown away anyway (not assigned back to `first`).

If you want to *change* things in a function (especially *multiple* things where you can return only one thing), you generally pass in pointers to them and use those pointers to change the originals. Hence your code could be rewritten as:

```c
void sort3(int *pFirst, int *pSecond, int *pThird) {
    // use *pFirst to get/set the ORIGINAL variable rather than a copy.
}

// called with:
sort3(&x, &y, &z);
```

And, rather than that complex shrubbery of `if` statements, you can just unroll a bubble sort to do the work for you, as shown in this complete program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void sort3(int *pOne, int *pTwo, int *pThree) {
    // Unrolled bubble sort:
    // Swap first/second if needed then
    // swap second/third if needed then
    // swap first/second if needed (yes, again, they may have changed).

    if (*pOne < *pTwo)   { int temp = *pOne; *pOne = *pTwo;   *pTwo   = temp; }
    if (*pTwo < *pThree) { int temp = *pTwo; *pTwo = *pThree; *pThree = temp; }
    if (*pOne < *pTwo)   { int temp = *pOne; *pOne = *pTwo;   *pTwo   = temp; }
}

void test(int a, int b, int c) {
    printf("%d %d %d -> ", a, b, c);
    sort3(&a, &b, &c);
    printf("%d %d %d : ", a, b, c);
    if (a >= b && b >= c) {
        puts("Good");
    } else {
        puts("*** BAD");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    for (int a = 1; a <= 3; ++a) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= 3; ++b) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 3; ++c) {
                test(a,b,c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the following output, this works for all cases:

```
1 1 1 -> 1 1 1 : Good
1 1 2 -> 2 1 1 : Good
1 1 3 -> 3 1 1 : Good
1 2 1 -> 2 1 1 : Good
1 2 2 -> 2 2 1 : Good
1 2 3 -> 3 2 1 : Good
1 3 1 -> 3 1 1 : Good
1 3 2 -> 3 2 1 : Good
1 3 3 -> 3 3 1 : Good
2 1 1 -> 2 1 1 : Good
2 1 2 -> 2 2 1 : Good
2 1 3 -> 3 2 1 : Good
2 2 1 -> 2 2 1 : Good
2 2 2 -> 2 2 2 : Good
2 2 3 -> 3 2 2 : Good
2 3 1 -> 3 2 1 : Good
2 3 2 -> 3 2 2 : Good
2 3 3 -> 3 3 2 : Good
3 1 1 -> 3 1 1 : Good
3 1 2 -> 3 2 1 : Good
3 1 3 -> 3 3 1 : Good
3 2 1 -> 3 2 1 : Good
3 2 2 -> 3 2 2 : Good
3 2 3 -> 3 3 2 : Good
3 3 1 -> 3 3 1 : Good
3 3 2 -> 3 3 2 : Good
3 3 3 -> 3 3 3 : Good
```

But, even if you decide to keep the *original* logic of your function, you *still* need to use the pointer method shown to affect all those variables outside said function.

I haven't bothered to validate your function since your immediate issue is just the values not being changed in the caller. And you can at least use the test harness I provided to validate that your approach works :-)

Comment: `first < second` should this not be `first > second`

Comment: @EdHeal: I don't believe so since the desired order is highest to lowest. Hence you only need to swap first/second if first is *less* than second.

Comment: I see the issue now! Thank you so much, I'm still new to C and don't quite get the logic yet

Answer (score 0):

if you gonna modify the parameters pass them by reference.

Answer (score 0):

always enable the warnings when compiling.
Then fix those warnings,

Compiling with `gcc` with most warnings enabled:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c" -o "untitled2.o"
```

The compiler outputs the following warnings:

```
untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled2.c:39:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘load’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   39 |     load(&x,&y,&z);
      |     ^~~~
      
untitled2.c:40:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘print’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   40 |     print(x,y,z);
      |     ^~~~~
      
untitled2.c:41:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   41 |     printf("\nThe middle element is %2d", middleElement(x,y,z));
      |     ^~~~~~
      
untitled2.c:41:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’

untitled2.c:1:1: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
  +++ |+#include <stdio.h>
    1 | int sort(int first, int second, int third) {
        
untitled2.c:41:43: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘middleElement’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   41 |     printf("\nThe middle element is %2d", middleElement(x,y,z));
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Notice that last line: *Compilation finished successfully.*
only means the compiler made a 'guess' as to what you actually wanted, not that the correct code was generated.